# Why does Windows say I have a 64-bit processor when it's not?

Tags: windows, cpu, 64-bit, 32-bit, device-manager

Windows tells me that I have a 64-bit processor:

[image]

However, checking in the Device Manager it says that my processor is 32 bit:

[image]

Why is that?

(I also notice that I have two duplicate processors?)

Comment: it's a 64-bit processor. What makes you believe its not? https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42809/intel-pentium-processor-e6700-2m-cache-3-20-ghz-1066-fsb.html most modern Intel processors are of the x86 family with support for 64-bit instructions. Windows shows each processor for each core

Comment: @Ramhound "You are aware all 64-bit processors are just 64-bit x86 processors, right?" No, this is new to me. I have thought x86 is just another way to say 32-bit (of course until now that I learn something new). Many installation list their 32-bit versions as x86

Comment: @Ramhound Just to clarify, all 64-bit modern *Intel* processors are x86. There are 64-bit processors which are not x86.

Comment: @Ooker x86 describes an instruction set (what commands are available for programmers to send to the CPU). There is a 64-bit extension to the x86 architecture called x86_64. A lot of people simply say "x86" to mean 32-bit nowadays, but that's not technically accurate - it's just that most software is compiled for the x86 architecture. There are other architectures in both 32 and 64-bit, such as ARM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your processor [is a 64-bit processor.](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42809/intel-pentium-processor-e6700-2m-cache-3-20-ghz-1066-fsb.html)

I'm not sure why it's showing up as x86 in your device manager (as opposed to x86_64), but it's mostly likely because your 32-bit installation of Windows will use the x86 instruction set and thus treat your 64-bit processor as if it was a 32-bit processor.

The two "duplicate" CPUs are actually the two physical cores on the CPU - it is a dual-core processor.